# Map a servlet to a cron url?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, android-studio, cron, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I map a servlet to a cron url? This question results from the comment to the answer in the following post: [Use Cron jobs with Appengine Endpoints API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438289/use-cron-jobs-with-appengine-endpoints-api)

In my project the cron job is called as shown in the log in Google App Engine and the url https://[url-commented-out].appspot.com/_ah/api/stocksApi/v1/stocks executes properly when tested in the web browser and returns the proper value.

But I am getting the error 405: HTTP method GET not supported by this URL, when I try to run it in GAE. I've read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron My code in cron.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/_ah/api/stocksApi/v1/stocks</url>
        <description>Backend Process Stocks</description>
       <schedule>every 1 minutes from 11:10 to 11:30</schedule>
       <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>

    </cron>
 </cronentries>
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                [package].StocksEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
            <security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>cron</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
                </web-resource-collection>
                <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>admin</role-name>
                </auth-constraint>
            </security-constraint>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using Android Studio and have added a backend module by following HelloEndpoints and I have a StocksEndpoint.java
file with a getStocks(); method that returns stocks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately urls under `/_ah/api` are restricted and cannot be called from within your App. 
There are a couple of ways to go around this but the most accepted option is usually to use a regular servlet to serve Cron requests rather connecting to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

First add a servlet mapping for your cron to web.xml:

```
<!--  stock servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StockServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE.StockServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StockServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cron/stocks</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**make sure to update the servlet class for your servlet!**

Then finally put the new cron url in your cron.xml:

```
<cron>
       <url>/cron/stocks</url>
       <description>Backend Process Stocks</description>
       <schedule>every 1 minutes from 11:10 to 11:30</schedule>
       <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
</cron>
```